# Add hide parameter to script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

hi I currently have the following script and I'm trying to add a show and hide feature to it instead of just having one hide and show it. essentially "click me" shows it and the button hides it, fiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/9M99G/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $('.below').hide();
    $('.toggleBtn').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.below').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Like `$('.below').on('click', function(){
            $(this).slideToggle();
        });` ?

Comment: If you could do it in answer form that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the same with the `.below` div and `slideToggle` it with `$(this)` :

```
$('.below').on('click', function(){
    $(this).slideToggle();
});
```

**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9M99G/2/)**

See more about [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Comment: Tried this earlier, but script was written much differently, this will work thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `slideToggle`

```
$('.below').on('click', function(){
 $(this).slideToggle(); 
});
```

That will switch display state; if hidden it will show, if shown it will be hidden

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the hide functionality for the button , this code will do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $('.below').hide();
    $('.toggleBtn').on('click', function () {
        $(this).next('.below').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
    $('.below').on('click', function(){
        $(this).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

`Demo fiddle` : http://jsfiddle.net/9M99G/4/

Or if you want to hide the `Click Me` while the hide button is being displayed the code below does exactly that

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $('.below').hide();
    $('.toggleBtn').on('click', function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.below').show();
        return false;
    });
    $('.below').on('click', function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.toggleBtn').show();
        return false;
    });

});
```

`Demo fiddle :` http://jsfiddle.net/9M99G/6/

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/9M99G/9/)**

Try this, use slideDown and slideUp

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('.below').hide();
        $('.toggleBtn').click(function () {
            $(this).next('.below').slideDown('slow');
            return false;
        });
         $('.below button').click(function () {
            $(".below").slideUp('slow');
        });
    });
```